# How to escape special characters from a textarea using jQuery post()

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, post

I have a form that is composed of a couple of text fields and a textarea for order **notes/comments**. The problem that I have is that every time I type a special character in the textarea the ajax request stops working. I've tried to escape the special characters using escape, escapeURIComponent, etc, but nothing seems to work. Removing the special characters works, but that doesn't solve my problem. Any suggestions? below is a snippet of the code I have:

```
$.post(getPost('addComponent'), {
                componentType:$('#componentType').val(),
                productQty:$('#productQty').val(),
                comments:$("#orderNotes").val()
            }, function(data, statusCode) {
        if (statusCode === 'success') {
            updateComponentContainer(data);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }, 'json');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `jQuery.serialize()`

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

** EDIT **

Look at this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nPdW9/

Comment: It is my understanding that serialize() serializes the entire form right? How would you do it for just one element? a text area in my case. Please let me know.

Comment: @Jrobertiko - You can serialize one element. Look at the jsFiddle I put in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the special characters are, but base64 encoding should solve the problem.

http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

and if you like to try before you buy, the demo page!

http://www.webtoolkit.info/demo/javascript-base64